# VB SqlAdapter Batch update: InsertCommand sends "NULL" to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have some SqlAdapter code that I've inherited. I have to admit, the code generally runs VERY well, but there is one method that is really acting strangely lately. When I attach SQL Server Profiler, it shows that the stored procedure is called, but all of the parameters being sent are NULL. I'm about to go nuts trying to track this down.

The Dataset that I'm passing to the oSqlAdapter object has all of the right data that I want to insert. The oSqlAdapter.InsertCommand has the correct stored procedure name and all of the correct parameters. I've tripple-checked the order and types of the parameters and the spelling of the parameters and the column names. WHAT ELSE could I be missing?

**Code:**

```
Dim rows as DataRow() = myDataSet.Tables(0).Select(Nothing, Nothing, _
                            DataViewRowState.Added)

... Create oSqlAdapter and connect the currentConnectionObject ...

With oSqlAdapter
    .InsertCommand = New SqlCommand()

    .InsertCommand.CommandText = "myStoredProc"
    .InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .InsertCommand.Connection  = currentConnectionObject

    AddParameter(.InsertCommand, "@Parm1", ParameterDirection.Input, "MyColumn1")
    AddParameter(.InsertCommand, "@Parm2", ParameterDirection.Input, "MyColumn2")
    AddParameter(.InsertCommand, "@Parm3", ParameterDirection.Input, "MyColumn3")
    AddParameter(.InsertCommand, "@ResultCode", ParameterDirection.Output, "MyResult")

    .Update(rows) '<--- Crashes here. When I connect Profiler, I see that 
                  '     the update did send the parameters, but the values
                  '     are always NULL, never the values in the DataRows.
End With

oSqlAdapter = Nothing
```

**The AddParameter logic is as follows:**

```
Public Sub AddParameter(cmd As SqlCommand, parmName As String,  _
    dir as ParameterDirectoni, colName as String)

    Dim oParm As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter(parmName, SqlDbType.Int)

    With oParm
        .Direction = dir
        .Value() = Nothing
        .SourceColumn = colName
    End With

    cmd.Parameters.Add(oParm)
    oParm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked rows? Maybe that is empty? Have you added rows to table?

Comment: "The Dataset that I'm passing to the oSqlAdapter object has all of the right data that I want to insert." Yes.

Comment: Are they all integers?  Maybe you have a type problem because the proc is specifying the type as an integer for all 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND THE BUG! (It was a sneaky one, too)

Apparently the datasource was attached to an Infragistics control through another user control on the same form. It was databound to this same datasource. The infragistics control was re-nullifying everything. Someone (long before I got here) had been writing items directly to the infragistics control (not to the datasource itself), so when you called the .Update() method, the control would intercept the command just before the actual update went through and the data in the datasource would get clobbered.

I appreciate everyone's suggestions, and I hope that this serves to help others in the near future.

For reference, **IF** you don't have something clobbering your datasource behind the scenes, the above code snip does work.

Answer (score 0):

In Public Sub AddParameter(), you're setting the value to nothing.

.Value() = Nothing

Comment: That's a placeholder for the real value that gets passed to it from the DataRow during the batch update.